# Are variables defined outside of a react component considered global?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that using global variables are a bad practice. I also know in javascript variables defined outside of a function are considered global. Is this also true for variables defined outside of a react component, be it a functional component or a class. It appears as no because some css in js libraries use syntax like this but I don't understand why it wouldn't be a global. For example:

```
import ...

const styles = ...

const MyComponent = () => {
   ...
}

export default MyComponent
```

Is styles a global variable here? Why or why not?

Comment: Read more about modules, but in short you define constant ```styles```, which you don't export after that. So you will not be able to use it anywhere else except in this module.

Comment: @AntoanElenkov thanks. Does this apply to test files as well? For example in jest you are not exporting anything so is the component.test.js file also a module or would variables defined outside any describe block or any function block for example at the top of the file be considered global?

Comment: @Isdmt, your test functions are not exported, because you do not use them anywhere else expect in this file when the the test engine executes them. If you define variable outside the functions, it will only be visible in this file and again it is NOT global and there is no such thing. If you want to use global variables, you can define and export one global object, where all of your global data can be assigned. But again, you should import this global object everywhere you want to use it. If it is not enough clear, I can write an answer with an example, let me know if you want me to do it.

Answer (score 3):

In React, as in many modern Javascript frameworks, they use script modules, which sandbox each script. This means that you cannot define a global unless you specifically assign something to the `window` object.

```
const local = {};
window.global = {};
```

A script module is defined by setting a script tag's type to be `module`:

```
<script type="module" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

You should see the resulting HTML that react creates contains these script types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I asked this in the comment above but wanted to ask under this answer as well: Does this apply to test files as well? For example in jest you are not exporting anything so is the component.test.js file also a module or would variables defined outside any describe block or any function block for example at the top of the file be considered global?